# Microsoft.NETCore.App for .NET Framework

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core app targeting .NET Framework 4.6.2.

I don't see  `Microsoft.NETCore.App` in my `project.json` file and when I try to upgrade some key NuGet packages from version 1.0.0 to 1.1.0, I get errors stating that dependencies could not be resolved.

Looks like I need to upgrade to .NET Core 1.1 but I'm still confused about this .NET Core vs. NET Framework business.

If my ASP.NET Core app is targeting .NET Framework 4.6.2, do I still:

1. Follow the article below to upgrade to .NET Core 1.1?https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/11/16/announcing-net-core-1-1/
2. Install  Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.1 on my project?

UPDATE:
I'm adding my project.json file below

```
{
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.2.306",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "net462": {
      "dependencies": {
        "MyClassLibrary1": {
          "target": "project"
        },
        "MyClassLibrary2": {
          "target": "project"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "**/*.cshtml",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "bower" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  },
  "tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.0.238",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  }
}
```

UPDATE 2:
ClassLibrary1 and ClassLibrary2 projects do not have project.json files. Here are their packages.config files.

ClassLibrary1 packages.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="9.0.1" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.ComponentModel.Annotations" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net462" />
</packages>
```

ClassLibrary2 packages.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB" version="1.11.3" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Core" version="2.0.4" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Edm" version="5.8.1" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.OData" version="5.8.1" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Services.Client" version="5.8.1" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Win32.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="NETStandard.Library" version="1.6.1" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="9.0.1" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Sendgrid" version="8.0.5" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="SendGrid.CSharp.HTTP.Client" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="StackExchange.Redis" version="1.2.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.AppContext" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.Collections" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.Collections.Concurrent" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.Console" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.Debug" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.Tools" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.Tracing" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.Globalization" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.Globalization.Calendars" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.IO" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.IO.Compression" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.IO.Compression.ZipFile" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.IO.FileSystem" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.Linq" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.Linq.Expressions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.Net.Http" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.Net.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.Net.Sockets" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.ObjectModel" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.Reflection" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.Reflection.Extensions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.Reflection.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.Resources.ResourceManager" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.Runtime" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.Extensions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.Handles" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.InteropServices" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.Numerics" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.Spatial" version="5.8.1" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.Text.Encoding" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.Text.Encoding.Extensions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.Text.RegularExpressions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.Threading" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.Threading.Tasks" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.Threading.Timer" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.Xml.ReaderWriter" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.Xml.XDocument" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="WindowsAzure.Storage" version="8.0.1" targetFramework="net462" />
</packages>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ASP.NET Core application can target multiple frameworks, if all dependencies it's using are also targeting same frameworks.

If any of the dependencies that you are using is not supporting .NET Core, you will get errors. Some of the errors can be mitigated through usage of imports.

Here is an example of entry in project.json file that specifies that ASP.NET Core application should be built for multiple frameworks:

```
 "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.1.0"
        }
      },
      "imports": [ "dnxcore50", "portable-net451+win8" ]
    },
    "net462": {}
  }
```

Comment: My app and all its dependencies are targeting .NET Framework 4.6.2. Should I then conclude that I should NOT have netcoreapp1.1 under frameworks? This all started because I tried to upgrade one of the NuGet packages and got errors. I can't seem to upgrade from 1.0.0 to 1.1.0. So concluded that I need to upgrade the whole ASP.NET Core app to 1.1.

Comment: Just added my project.json file to the original post. When I try to upgrade "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication": "1.0.0" to version 1.1.0, I get an error saying the dependency could not be resolved. I'm getting the same error with any NuGet upgrade from 1.0.0 to 1.1.0. That's why I concluded that I need to upgrade the app to Core 1.1 as stated in the article I linked in original post.

Comment: Can you post contents of project.json files for your MyClassLibrary1 and MyClassLibrary2 projects?

Comment: The class library projects do not have project.json files. I updated the original post with their packages.config files.

Comment: Ok, I am now confused on what are you trying to accomplish here. If you have MyClassLibrary1 and MyClassLibrary2 as traditional projects set to .NET Framework 4.6.2, then you are bound to use .NET 4.6.2. It does not prevent you from using ASP.NET Core on top of that though. If you have dependencies errors in project.json when you change to 1.1.0, expand references tree until you find which package in dependency chain is causing the error. Have you tried to update all your packages to 1.1.0 and not only one of them? Could be that you have conflict on some common sub-dependency.

Comment: As I mentioned in the original post, my app is .NET Framework 4.6.2 all the way. What I'm trying to do is simply update NuGet packages because I'm seeing some 17 updates available. When I try though, I get errors -- as mentioned in the original post. My confusion stems from ASP.NET Core which can target the .NET Core or .NET Framework. I'm not sure if I need to somehow upgrade my app to ASP.NET Core 1.1 targeting .NET Framework. During my research, I found a similar question and the person who responded suggested that the app itself had to be upgraded to Core 1.1.

Comment: I'm just not sure if this only applies to ASP.NET Core apps targeting .NET Core or it means all ASP.NET Core apps need to go through an upgrade regardless of which framework they target.